# Read wifi status with powershell

Tags: powershell, wifi

I want to read the state of a wifi adapter. For example I want to know if the wifi device connected to an access point.

Is it possible to do it with powershell?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this might do it

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
   public enum NetConnectionStatus
   {
        Disconnected=0,
        Connecting=1,
        Connected=2,
        Disconnecting=3,
        Hardware_Not_present=4,
        Hardware_disabled=5,
        Hardware_malfunction=6,
        Media_disconnected=7,
        Authenticating=8,
        Authentication_succeeded=9,
        Authentication_failed=10,
        Invalid_address=11,
        Credentials_required=12
   }
"@

$Adaptors = Get-WmiObject -class win32_networkadapter -filter "Name like '%wireless%'" | select name, deviceID, NetConnectionStatus

foreach ($adaptor in $Adaptors){
    "$($adaptor.deviceID) : $($adaptor.name) : $([NetConnectionStatus]::GetName([NetConnectionStatus],$adaptor.NetConnectionStatus))"
}
```

Comment: It doesn't answer though what wireless profile it is connected to akin to what `netsh wlan show interfaces` reports.

Comment: I know this is old but if you reread your question you didnt ask for the wireless profile. You asked what is the State of the adapter.